# Parsing Json to convert into DTO

Tags: java, jsonparser

I want to convert following JSON

```
{
  "docType": {
    "order": 1,
    "type": "String"
  },
  "docNum": {
    "order": 2,
    "type": "String"
  },
  "amount": {
    "order": 3,
    "type": "Double"
  }
}
```

into DTO by parsing above JSON let say

OutPutFileDTO of 
  private String doctype,
  private String docNum,
  private Double amount,

Note: order refers ordering of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to use Jackson( https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-how-to-parse-json/ ) of Gson( https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-parse-json-with-gson/ )